# How to create random keys in certain styles for the primary key

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert a row into a table and the table has a primary key that follows a certain style. One example would be:

```
C140E30C-7BED-45C1-B514-AFB184C415D0
```

The key is a mixture of alphabets and numbers and values are separated by "-" in the key. How do I create a primary key that follows this style?

Comment: It's a GUID.  Use function Newid()

Comment: If you want SQL Server to automatically assign the value, create a default constraint on the PK column with a default value of `NEWSEQIENTIALID()`.

Comment: How much random do you really need them to be? GUID is rather bad PK, NEWSEQIENTIALID is not that random, but makes GUID less bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    colname INT
)

INSERT INTO sometable (id, colname)
    SELECT NEWID(), 'test'
```